# How to generate Pdf file for my resume builder app?

Tags: flutter, pdf, latex, flutter-dependencies

Currently I'm making Resume Builder App in flutter. Everything other components are working for MVP expect converting User data into Pdf.

Right now I am creating Pdf manually using dart_pdf and Printing plugins but fonts and size are not look like what I expected to be it(tho I'm using same size and font family like its in templates). And also using this approach I will have to make all resume templates by hand.

Other approach I was thinking was parsing Latex file into pdf but couldn't find anything thats works.

Also I want it to make it offline , so online services are no good.

If you have build something like this or have idea please share.
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 3):

You can use flutter_html_to_pdf package

```
   Future<void> generatePdf() async {
//HTML content with styling
final htmlContent = '''
<html>
  <head>
    <style>
      body {
        font-family: 'Arial, sans-serif';
        font-size: 14px;
        color: #333;
      }
      h1 {
        color: #007bff;
      }
      /*custom styling*/
    </style>
  </head>
  <body>
    <h1>Resume Title</h1>
    <p>resume content</p>
  </body>
</html>
''';

 final String generatedPdfFilePath =
  await FlutterHtmlToPdf.convertFromHtmlContent(htmlContent);

print('PDF generated at: $generatedPdfFilePath');
}
```